# Python - Changing to Memoization

Tags: python, memoization

I've coded a function that finds all changes of n using the given coins when order makes a change.

```
def find_change(n, coins):
    if n < 0:
        return []

    if n == 0:
        return [[]]

    all_changes = []

    for last_used_coin in coins:
        curr_changes = find_change(n - last_used_coin, coins)

        for change in curr_changes:
            change.append(last_used_coin)

        all_changes.extend(curr_changes)

    return all_changes

print find_change(4, [1,2,3])
```

The code above is "normal" and now I want to code it again but as a memo. The values that will be saved in the memo are mutable therefore I should use deepcopy but I don't know how to use it. Can someone show me how?

EDIT:
idea how to use deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
lst1 =[[1], [2]]
lst 2 = deepcopy(lst1)
print lst
```

and we get:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: Your code does not execute, please post a working version of this function. For starters, `find_changes` is a typo, but the function does not complete execution. Please also post a working example of using the function.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but the code still does not execute

Comment: @PeterGibson - sorry, what about now?

Answer (score 2):

Your only changing argument is `n`, so just use it as the key for your lookup table:

```
if n not in cache:
    ...
```

You could even turn it into a decorator:

```
def memoized(function):
    cache = {}

    def inner(n, coins):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = function(n, coins)

        return cache[n]

    return inner

@memoized
def find_change(n, coins):
    ...
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. But, I would really want to use deepcopy, I tried to undertstand how it works and how to make this code in memo but I had no success. I would really like if you could try to do this way. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3210483: Using `deepcopy` won't make your list immutable. Your list doesn't change in the first place, so why use it as the key for a lookup table? The only thing that changes is `n`.

Comment: I have an idea how to try to use deepcopy, please look at my edit in the first message. thanks.

Comment: @user3210483: Change `cache[n] = function(n, coins)` to `cache[n] = deepcopy(function(n, coins))` and I guess

Comment: Perhaps `coins` is *supposed* to change? This would make sense given the desire to use deepcopy. @user3210483 Are you selecting change from a limited set of coins?

Comment: @Blender - can you edit it? I can't understand this way

Comment: @PeterGibson - the "coins" is a number that is given in the beginning, same as "n"

Comment: @user3210483: `deepcopy` won't help you here. Memoization maps a function's inputs to its output in a lookup table, so the only thing you need to do is map `n` to `find_change(n, coins)`. Why are you insisting on using `deepcopy`?

Comment: @Blender - I've been requested to do it this way.

Comment: @Blender Can you explain please the decorator - where it comes in the find_change code?

Comment: @user3210483: Nowhere, it comes right before the function definition, exactly how I wrote it. It's equivalent to writing `find_change = memoized(old_find_change)`.

Comment: I suspect that you're given a set of coins and each iteration of the loop is supposed to remove one coin from that set. Could you edit your post to add the full question?

Comment: @Blender - can you show me the other way, of writing its with "="?

Comment: @PeterGibson - indeed, I get the coins. For example: 
find_changes(10,[5,10]) will give me that:
[[5, 5], [10]]

Comment: @user3210483: I think PeterGibson meant that you have a fixed number of coins, like `find_change(20, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10]) == [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10]]`.

Comment: @Blender - Sorry, didn't unserstand what you wrote. I'll try to give another example:find_changes(10,[10]) will give that: [[10]]. Another example is: find_changes(4,[1,2,3]) ---> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3]]

Comment: @user3210483: Then what you have in your question is correct. The only changing input to your function is `n`, so that's the key you use to cache results.

Comment: @Blender - not sure I understand. Can you explain please?